# Blocking vs Non-Blocking - Performance Differences

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, blocking, nonblocking

I am responsible for implementing a Websocket Endpoint, whose sequence of flow is like this:

1. Check if the request is valid.
2. If valid, hit another backend service for analysis.
3. Once the response is received, convert into a specific structure and return to client.

The websocket service is written in Java using Spring 4 and running on Tomcat 8.5. I am using default connector in Tomcat.

I had two options:

Option 1 - Hit the backend service in a blocking manner.

```
HttpRequest request = Unirest.get(url).queryString(params);     
HttpResponse<String> response = request.asString();
//return response to client.
```

Option 2 - Hit the backend service in a non-blocking manner.

```
HttpRequest request = Unirest.get(url).queryString(params);
request.asStringAsync(new Callback<String>() {
@Override
public void failed(UnirestException e) {}

@Override
public void completed(HttpResponse<String> response) {
String result = response.getBody().toString();
// return result to client
});
```

The average response time from the backend service is always ~400ms.

I load testing the application in "blocking" as well as "non-blocking" modes. To my surprise, the results were bit different from my expectations:

1. The average response time of "non-blocking" approach was slightly lower than the "blocking" approach.
2. There were substantially more errors in the "non-blocking" implementation than "blocking" (connection, timeout errors).
3. Garbage collection was working overtime to clear objects in "non-blocking" implementation with high spikes in JVisualVM. GC performance was much more smooth in blocking implementation.

Results suggest that I should be using blocking approach instead of non-blocking. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I think the existence of netty says your conclusion is quite wrong.  https://netty.io/

Comment: Blocking uses far more threads under load.

Answer (score -1):

CPU Usage and Throughput is a major difference between blocking and Non-Blocking system, for more information please refer this.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/differences-between-blocking-vs-non-blocking-systems-ashish-modi

Comment: Would you mind taking a moment to expand on your answer, specifically *quoting the most relevant part of your link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently* offline. [Answering questions guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)